# Is there some research paper which focus on the influence of using cancer cell as experimental materials on experimental result?

Tags: cell-biology, cancer, experimental-design, literature

Cancer cell is unstable cell and high variation, but there are many experiment use cancer cell as experimental materials. I always wonder how much influence can using cancer cell as experimental materials exert over experimental result?

Is there any study about this? If any, please give me the study paper.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Depends on what is the objective of the experiment. In some cases the cancer cells are decent models while they are poor for others. You need to specify what kind of experimental objectives you are interested in. You should also remember that no model is perfect. They are useful and good approximations for certain conditions and you need to know these conditions beforehand.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. What interests me is evaluating existing result which have been published. Not the experiment design.

Comment: That is just too broad. We cannot evaluate all the published literature for problems in the experimental design. Do you mean to ask if there are studies that have done this kind of survey? Again there are many articles on this topic. Did you try a google search?

Comment: I have tried scholar. I didn't get satisfied answer, can you give some paper  that focus on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

There are several articles on this. You may look at these for a start:

1. Masters, John RW. "[Human cancer cell lines: fact and fantasy.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/35043102)" *Nature reviews Molecular cell biology* 1.3 (2000): 233-236.
2. Masters, John R. “[False Cell Lines: The Problem and a Solution.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023%2FA%3A1022908930937)” *Cytotechnology* 39.2 (2002): 69–74.
3. Masters, John R. "[HeLa cells 50 years on: the good, the bad and the ugly](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nrc775)." *Nature Reviews Cancer* 2.4 (2002): 315-319.
4. Holliday, Deborah L., and Valerie Speirs. "[Choosing the right cell line for breast cancer research.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21884641)" *Breast Cancer Res* 13.4 (2011): 215.
5. Lacroix, Marc. "[Persistent use of “false” cell lines.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/ijc.23233)" *International journal of cancer* 122.1 (2008): 1-4.